# Wolfram Mathematica: Direction fields graphing

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Trying to figure out this question here:
Plot direction field for the differential equation

```
dy/dx=sin(x^2+y^2)log(|x+y|) when -1<x,y<1.
```

You will have full grade if you will make intervals of the plot 
all of the same length. Make the grid 20 X 20.

Here's my non working code:

```
StreamPlot[{1, (Sin[y^2+x^2]*Log[Abs[x+y]])}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, RegionFunction->Function[{x,y}, {{-1<x<1}&&{-1<y<1}}]]
```

Can't understand Wolfram syntax. Any tips much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand all what you asked. If your aim is to plot the direction field with a grid involving 20x20=400 points, a possible way to do this is:

```
grid = Range[-1, 1, 2/19]
points = Apply[Join, Outer[{#1, #2} &, grid, grid]];
VectorPlot[{1, (Sin[y^2 + x^2]*Log[Abs[x + y]])}, 
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   VectorPoints -> points, 
   GridLines -> {grid, grid}]
```

`grid`, of length=20, is:

```
{-1, -(17/19), -(15/19), -(13/19), -(11/19), -(9/19), -(7/19), -(5/19),
-(3/19), -(1/19), 1/19, 3/19, 5/19, 7/19, 9/19, 11/19, 13/19, 15/19,
 17/19, 1}
```

`points` is the grid Cartesian product:

```
{{-1, -1}, {-1, -(17/19)}, {-1, -(15/19)}, {-1, -(13/19)}, ...}
```

The vectors (1,f(x,y)) of your ODE y'=f(x,y) are evaluted for each point of `points`. The resulting plot is:

[image]

---

Below, some clarifications about the Mathematica syntax & your question:

The `RegionFunction` option allows you to plot in some specified region. For instance, you can restrict the vector field to be plotted in the unit disk:

```
VectorPlot[{1, (Sin[y^2 + x^2]*Log[Abs[x + y]])},
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    VectorPoints -> points, GridLines -> {grid, grid}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]]
```

[image]

Your code does not work because your boolean expression (the body part of the pure function):

```
Function[{x, y}, {{-1<x<1}&&{-1<y<1}}]
```

does not respect the Mathematica syntax.

The Mathematica way to write it is:

```
 Function[{x, y}, (-1<x<1)&&(-1<y<1)]
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, it works. Is there any way I can make the arrows the same size?